# Como solucionar los Errores AndroidManifest.xml al poner icono en Toolbar

Tags: android-studio

porque al cambiar en el **MainActivity.java** el toolbar para poder poner *un icono en el toolbat* me muestra errores en el **AndroidManifest.xml** que antes no tenia.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Titulo Aqui");
       getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
```

Para que veáis los errores del AndroidManifest.xml mejor pongo una captura.

**AndroidManifest.xml**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me podéis decir cómo hacer para quitar esos errores?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

pongo aquí por si alguien más se encuentra con el mismo problema.

Intenté buscar una solución antes de postearlo y no la encontré, de todas formas, lo pondré por si con esta segunda solución le puede servir a alguien, en algún caso decían que hay que ir a:

- Ir a "Archivo> Estructura del proyecto> Módulos"
- Haga clic en "agregar (+) "
- Haga clic en "androide" y "Aplicar" y luego "OK"

Yo la verdad que no encontré la opción de **Android** para poder aplicarlo.
Si alguien sabe dónde está, por favor que lo diga....

En mi caso se solucionó cerrando todas las pestañas o módulos que tenía abiertos, y al volver abrir en AndroidManifest.xml ya no tenia esos errores.

Gracias a los que se han molestado en leer el post, jeje,